# Graph classes where finding explicit coloring have certificate that it is minumum

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Graph coloring doesn't have certificate that smaller coloring doesn't exist in general.

I am looking for graph classes where finding explicit coloring is not polynomial and have polynomially verifiable certificate that it is minimum.

Example of such class might be graphs for which the clique number equals
the chromatic number, i.e. $\omega(G)=\chi(G)$ and
finding coloring is not polynomial. Find both coloring and clique and the
clique will be certificate that smaller coloring doesn't exist
because of the inequality $\omega(G) \le \chi(G)$.

> Are there nice characterizations of such graph classes
>   (preferably by forbidden induced subgraphs)?

[Paper](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/140801/CzechMathJ_60-2010-4_11.pdf) defines such graphs "weakly perfect" and claims that
deciding $\omega(G)=\chi(G)$ is NP-complete.

Near misses are perfect and cobipartite but there the problems
are polynomial.

Comment: NP-complete = {in NP + NP-hard}, so your question doesn't make sense. Maybe there is a confusion?

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud I don't think showing that k-coloring doesn't exist is NP-complete since you don't have certificate. Do you agree with this? NP-Complete requires certificate. Maybe I mean not in coNP?

Comment: The revised question does not make sense either. *No* NP-complete problem is in coNP, unless NP =coNP.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK, thanks. Is there any hope in saving the question in case the other part makes sense?

Comment: I honestly do not understand what you are after. Since you seem to be confused about basic  definitions, it might help if you rewrite the question avoiding terms like NP-complete and NP-hard, and explicitly express it using reductions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK, just edited asking for certificate that the coloring is minimum which I believe is not guaranteed by coloring.

Comment: Thanks, this is much more clear. However, I still do not understand the "and clique and coloring are NP-hard" part. If $\omega(G)=\chi(G)$, then clique and colouring are both in $\mathrm{NP}\cap\mathrm{coNP}$, hence they cannot be NP-hard unless NP=coNP. More generally, colouring is in $\mathrm{NP}\cap\mathrm{coNP}$ if and only if minimum colourings have NP certificates.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This is additional restriction to avoid clique and coloring in P which is trivial.

Comment: So, do you just want to demand that clique and colouring are not in P? As I already explained, the restriction does not make sense as stated.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks will edit. Yes, I want only coloring to not be in P to avoid triviality. btw, In some sense "weakly perfect" are kind of answer, but this is just a name.

Comment: I think you are misreading the paper. Deciding *membership* in the class of weakly perfect graphs is NP-complete, however, deciding *colouring* on this class is quite easy: given a graph such that $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$, one can compute $\chi(G)$ in polynomial time using the Lovász theta function.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I wrote NPC about membership, didn't know theta works. So you mean weakly perfect don't work for the question because of polynomial coloring?

Comment: Yes, exactly. –

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Not sure if this makes sense, but is computing $\chi(G)$ of weakly chordal enough for finding a coloring (my question)? This will give an algorithm for coloring all graphs for which the equality happens by chance OEIS A198634

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I edited asking for finding explicit coloring. Likely will accept yours as answer if you would bother. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Colouring is a decision problem, not a search problem: given $G$ and $k$, decide whether $G$ has a $k$-colouring. The paper http://www.zib.eu/groetschel/pubnew/paper/groetschellovaszschrijver1984b.pdf is quite hazy about the distinction, but it seems that the algorithm does, in fact, also construct an optimal colouring, for perfect graphs (which includes weakly chordal). Now, I’m quite puzzled by your last comment, because my point was that this particular class does *not* answer the question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK. You answer that my suggested approach doesn't work.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek RE the paper you gave: You write "...include weakly **chordal**" repeating my typo in comments. I am asking about weakly **perfect** which are not subset of perfect. Sorry for the typo in the comments.

Comment: I see. No, I don’t know how to construct colourings efficiently for just weakly perfect graphs. In fact, it sounds likely to be impossible: if we could do that, we could construct a $k$-colouring of any given $k$-colourable graph by taking its disjoint union with a $k$-clique, which makes the graph weakly perfect.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Indeed, I thought about the same. Searching the web for weakly **perfect** return algebraic constructions of such (rings/fields). In all papers I found both clique and coloring were polynomial via closed form.

Answer (score 4):

One possible answer is the class of all $3$-chromatic graphs.  That is, suppose I tell you that your input graph $G$ is $3$-chromatic and I ask you to find an optimal colouring.  Evidently, every $3$-colouring will be its own certificate of optimality.  On the other hand, it turns out that knowing that your graph is $3$-chromatic does not help much in finding an optimal colouring.  I believe the state of the art is a paper of [Kawarabayashi and Thorup](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1254v1.pdf) which finds a $O(n^{0.2038})$-colouring in polynomial time for input graphs that are $3$-colourable.  For hardness results, it is NP-hard to find a $5$-colouring in polynomial-time even knowing that your input graph is $3$-colourable.  In fact, assuming a version of the Unique Games Conjecture, it is NP-hard to find a $O(1)$-colouring in polynomial-time for $3$-colourable graphs.

Comment: Interesting. Isn't a simpler certificate the fact that it is not bipartite?

Comment: @joro: In Tony Huynh's setting, our input universe is the set of 3-chromatic graphs, that is, we know they are all non-bipartite and 3-colorable. Therefore it only makes sense to have a certificate depending on the output coloring.

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud Indeed, but this can be extended to all graphs for which 3-coloring is found without the promise.